# How to read JSON objects from Tweet.py results

Tags: python, json, twitter, tweepy

I am trying to read the JSON file created by Tweet.py. However, whatever I tried I am receiving an ValueError consistently.

ValueError: Expecting property name: line 1 column 3 (char 2)

JSON results are in the format of:

```
{ 'Twitter Data' : [ {
"contributors": null, 
"coordinates": null, 
"created_at": "Tue Oct 24 15:55:21 +0000 2017", 
"entities": {
    "hashtags": ["#football"]
   }            
} , {
"contributors": johnny, 
"coordinates": null, 
"created_at": "Tue Oct 24 15:55:21 +0000 2017", 
"entities": {
    "hashtags": ["#football" , "#FCB"]
   }             
} , ... ] }
```

There are at least 50 of these JSON objects in the file, which are separated by commas.

My Python script to read this json file is:

```
twitter_data=[]
with open('@account.json' , 'r') as json_data:
    for line in json_data:
        twitter_data.append(json.loads(line))

print twitter_data
```

Tweet.py writes these Json objects by using:

```
json.dump(status._json,file,sort_keys = True,indent = 4)
```

I would appreciate any help and guidance on how to read this file!

Thank you.

Comment: Would you please provide a complete, but much smaller sample JSON file?

Comment: Yes, of course @ChristopherBottoms

Comment: 1) `'` is not a legal string delimter in JSON, and 2) your code expects a new JSON doc every line, but your sample is a single JSON doc that happens to take multiple lines.

Answer (score 1):

The `{ 'Twitter Data'` bit should be `{ "Twitter Data"` as well as `"Johnny"`

That is to say keys and values (strings) must be enclosed in double quotes.

```
with open("@account.json","r") as json_data:
    data = json_data.readlines()
    twitter_data.append(json.loads(data))
```

Also, Haven't used this myself but this might be of help as well: https://jsonlint.com

Comment: I got the following error when I tried this:  in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
TypeError: expected string or buffer

Answer (score 0):

First off, as both @Rob and @silent have noted, `'Twitter Data'` should be `"Twitter Data"`. Json needs double quotes, not single quotes to delimit a string.

Secondly, when reading with `json.load()` it expects a `file` Object, so when calling `json.load()`, just pass in `json_data` and it will read the whole json file into memory:

```
with open('@account.json' , 'r') as json_data:
    contents = json.load(json_data)
```

EDIT:

for handling multiple objects at once:

```
def get_objs(f):
    content = f.read()

    # Get each object in the contents of the file object.
    # This is kinda clunky and inelegant, but it should work
    objs = ['{}{}'.format(i, '}') for i in content.split('},')]

    # Last json_obj probably got an unnecessary "}" at the end, so trim the
    # last character from it
    objs[-1] = objs[-1][0:-1]

    json_objs = [json.loads(i) for i in objs]
    return json_objs
```

and then just go:

```
with open('@account.json', 'r') as json_data:
    json_objs = get_objs(json_data)
```

Hopefully this will work for you. It did for me when I tested it on a simalarly formatted json file.

Comment: I made the edits and just tried. I got the following error: ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded

Comment: Ah, I notice now you said there would be multiple json objects in each. I have came up with a possible solution. Editing now.

Comment: @Pythoner1234: The multiple objects you refer to are the 'multiple' objects within the list key `Twitter Data` right? or are there multiple `Twitter Data` objects? can you list 2 or 3 objects so that we are clear on the structure of the JSON file.

Comment: I got the following error when I attempted this: anaconda/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 382, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded

Comment: Can you provide a better example of your json file like @silent asked so we better know the structure of the file?